# Why does injections binding into UIViewRepresentable causes memory leak?

Tags: swiftui, memory-management, memory-leaks, binding, uiviewrepresentable

I've just started learning SwiftUI and I use Date Picker via UIViewRepresentable and I'm injection binding into it because I want to update my date property in View Model. When I open memory graph I see there is few instances of that view model so it causes memory leak. But when I comment Binding property in Date picker there is no memory leak. Does anyone know how to inject binding without memory issues? Here is the code:

**Date Picker class (UIViewRepresentable)**

```
struct DatePickerTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let textField = BaseTextField()
    private let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    private let helper = Helper()
    public var typeOfDatePicker: TypeOfDatePicker
    public var placeholder: String
    @Binding public var date: String
    @Binding var dateLimit: String

func setDate() {
    let dateVar = DateHelper.getFullDate.string(from: datePicker.date)
    
    switch typeOfDatePicker {
    case .startDate:
        if let endDate = DateHelper.createDateFromString(dateLimit) {
            if datePicker.date <= endDate {
                date = dateVar
            }
        } else {
            date = dateVar
        }
    case .endDate:
        if let startDate = DateHelper.createDateFromString(dateLimit) {
            if datePicker.date >= startDate {
                date = dateVar
            }
        } else {
            date = dateVar
        }
    }
    
    setDatePickerLimits()
}

func setDatePickerLimits() {
    switch typeOfDatePicker {
    case .startDate:
        datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: Date())
        if dateLimit != "" {
            datePicker.maximumDate = DateHelper.createDateFromString(dateLimit)
        } else {
            datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: Date())
        }
    case .endDate:
        if dateLimit != "" {
            datePicker.minimumDate = DateHelper.createDateFromString(dateLimit)
        } else {
            datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: Date())
        }
        datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: Date())
    }
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
    
    setDatePickerLimits()
    datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: L10n.calendarLocaleIdentifier)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    datePicker.addTarget(self.helper, action: #selector(self.helper.dateValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    
    textField.placeholder = placeholder
    textField.backgroundColor = Asset.backgroundTextFiledViewColor.color
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: L10n.titleChoose, style: .plain, target: helper, action: #selector(helper.doneButtonTapped))
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: L10n.buttonTitleCancel, style: .plain, target: helper, action: #selector(helper.cancelButtonTapped))
    
    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: true)
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    
    helper.onDateValueChanged = {
        setDate()
    }
 
    helper.onDoneButtonTapped = {
        setDate()
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    helper.onCancelButtonTapped = {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    return textField
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {

        uiView.text = date

}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}

class Helper {
    public var onDateValueChanged: (() -> Void)?
    public var onDoneButtonTapped: (() -> Void)?
    public var onCancelButtonTapped: (() -> Void)?
    
    @objc func dateValueChanged() {
        onDateValueChanged?()
        
    }
    
    @objc func doneButtonTapped() {
        onDoneButtonTapped?()
    }
    
    @objc func cancelButtonTapped() {
        onCancelButtonTapped?()
    }
}

class Coordinator {}
```

}

**And here is its usage in View:**

```
DatePickerTextField(typeOfDatePicker: .startDate,
 placeholder: L10n.textAvailableFrom, date: $createNewOffersViewModel.offersDTO.seasonStart,
 dateLimit: $createNewOffersViewModel.offersDTO.seasonEnd)
                            .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .onChange(of: $createNewOffersViewModel.offersDTO.seasonStart.wrappedValue) { newValue in
                                if !newValue.isEmpty {
                                    self.createNewOffersViewModel.createOfferValidation[CreateNewOfferValidationEnum.seasonStart] = true
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DatePickerTextField` is a struct and it is init and thrown away every time SwiftUI updates. Thus you have to be careful not to init any objects when the struct inits because thats a major memory leak and performance hit. Looks to me like you are initing `UIDatePicker` objects and a few other things in the struct. You need to move these object inits into local vars inside `makeUIView` so they only happen once.

Then use `updateUIView` to copy all the struct's new values into the `UIView` object. `updateUIView` is called when any lets changed from the last time this struct was init, or if any `@Binding var` changes.

As long as `DatePickerTextField` stays in the same place in the hierarchy it will find the correct `UIView` object.

Comment: There is no more memory leak, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I just realized while testing that date picker now doesn’t work, objc func are called just once?

Comment: you need to move the objc funcs into the Coordinator